# create an ASP.net web api for azure CDN purge

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am uploading  a file to blob.I am using purge to file edit,but doing it manually now.I need Asp.net web Api code to  clear the cache.By calling the web api i can clear the cache automatically.Anybody can help me on this is appreciated,since I am a beginner to this industry.Thank you!!!!

Comment: you need to upload some code

Answer (score 0):

Kindly take a look at the below link:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/endpoints/purgecontent

You can implement an api endpoint in your asp.net web api project wrapping the azure management rest api endpoint in its raw form or you can use an azure CDN sdk for .net.